# Fourier series of $f(x) = 1$ on the interval $\pi/2 < |x| < \pi$

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

I am trying to calculate the Fourier series of $f(x) = 1$ on the interval $\pi/2 < |x| < \pi$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

$f(x) = 1$ is an even function. Therefore, $b_n = 0$.

I am troubling how to proceed with the interval due to the absolute value in this case. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Is $f(x)=0$ outside this interval (these two intervals)?

Comment: Yess, outside the interval it’s zero

Comment: If you could do this for $\pi/2 < x < \pi$ then it would be easy enough to do it for $-\pi < x < -\pi/2$ and then add the two results together.  Or if you prefer even functions then you could do it for $-\pi < x < \pi$ and for $-\pi /2 \le x \le \pi/2$ and subtract

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, [plot it out](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5BUnitStep%5BAbs%5Bx%5D-Pi%2F2%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-Pi%2CPi%7D%5D). Your function looks like this:

[image]

It's $0$ in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and $1$ in the intervals $(-\pi, -\pi/2)$ and $(\pi/2,\pi)$. From this we can determine
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(k x)dx = \int_{-\pi}^{-\pi/2}\cos(kx)dx + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \cos(k x)dx.
$$
You can use standard integration techniques to evaluate this integral and find the Fourier coefficients. If you do it all right, you should get $a_0 = 1/2$, $a_{2n} = 0$, and $a_{2n-1} = (-1)^n 2/[(2n-1)\pi]$.

Comment: Thank you! I now see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$f(x)=0$ for $x \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

and

$f(x)=1$  for $x \in ( -\pi,\pi) \setminus [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: This is what I understand. I am struggling how to visualize and put it into integral form to calculate $a_0$ and $a_n$.